# Salesforce Workflow Rule

Tags: workflow, flow, date, force

I am new to salesforce and I was wondering how could you set the rule criteria to be evaluated when the current date is equal to chosen date in the EVENT DATE field in the opportunity object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this formula to be evaluated as rule criteria:

```
EventDate__c = TODAY()
```

It will work.

Comment: Please mark the best answer

Answer (score 1):

You have to create `Workflow rule` with time-dependant action to trigger it when `EVENT DATE` equals Today (this could be a `Field update` that will trigger your `Workflow rule`). You have to check 'Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change' flag for this to happen.

Answer (score -1):

Currently Salesforce doesn't allow a workflow rule to be triggered when the current date matches a date field.  A workaround for this is to create a workflow that is triggered when the field EVENT DATE is populated. The workflow then needs to have a time trigger that is set to fire 0 days after EVENT DATE.

If EVENT DATE is a formula field, then it may require Apex code to make this fully automated.